# How to disable directory browsing in websphere 8.5?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I need to know how I could disable ability to retrieve list of js/css files from browser when user tries to access resource folder instead of file itself  (e.g. by typing `http://domain/appname/resources/js`) on webshere 8.5.

According IBM Knowledge Center documentation [Web Container](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_config_webContainer.html) default value for `directoryBrowsingEnabled` is `false` which suggest that I do not necessary need define: `<enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>` on `ibm-web-ext.xml` in the first place.

On my case WebSphere generates `ibm-web-ext.xml` with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/>
    <jsp-attribute name="reloadInterval" value="5"/>
</web-ext>
```

In case I modify and replace `ibm-web-ext.xml` with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/>
    <jsp-attribute name="reloadInterval" value="5"/>
    <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
</web-ext>
```

After application restart seems nothing changed.

Why CSS / JS resources files list accessible from browser even if `directoryBrowsingEnabled` flag is set to `false`? Seems like `directoryBrowsingEnabled` alone isn't enough. What do I missing?

Comment: is the OPs syntax correct?      <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/> in ibm-web-ext.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: directory browsing for WAS is already disabled by default.

Please note that 'directory browsing' mean to be FTP style directory browsing when user can navigate directories by clicking folders upwards / downwards.

My case browsers responds with 200 code by downloading folder as plain text file when user hits `http://domain/appname/resources/js`. So it's not previously mentioned 'FTP' style browsing case.

Along with other static resource configuration there was spring mvc resource tag.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/resources/" />
```

I do not think that tag alone was cause of this issue. However, by removing it resource directories URL no longer resulting in 200 status code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable static file browsing in the web application level, Set the "fileServingEnabled" property to FALSE as well in the ibm-web-ext.xml file.

```
fileServingEnabled="false"
```

If you want to disable it globally (All the applications in the application server), then Use the `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.disallowAllFileServing` custom property

Answer (score 0):

By the way of removing

<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/resources/" />

The application also cannot retrieve some resources for displaying.